# run all arquillian tests from outside container

Tags: jboss-arquillian

In order to automate the testing for a web project, is it possible to deploy the standard complete archive and then run arquillian tests?
What I've been doing so far is creating arquillian tests and then running from eclipse/terminal, which will deploy only selected classes and then run arquillian test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Arquillian tests will deploy its custom ear/war to jboss and execute test cases.